# Interactive book [Minecraft 1.8.8 Spigot]

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

This question is about Spigot 1.8.8 (Minecraft).

Hello! I want to create an interactive book (click and hover events) and don't know how. I searched many hours but found nothing that worked for me.

I tried this code:

```java
ItemStack book = new ItemStack(Material.WRITTEN_BOOK);
                BookMeta bookMeta = (BookMeta) book.getItemMeta();

                BaseComponent[] page = new ComponentBuilder("Click")
                        .event(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.OPEN_URL, "http://spigotmc.org"))
                        .event(new HoverEvent(HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT, new ComponentBuilder("Thanks for hovering").create()))
                        .create();

                bookMeta.spigot().addPage(page);

                bookMeta.setTitle("test");
                bookMeta.setAuthor("test");

                book.setItemMeta(bookMeta);
```

But bookMeta.spigot().addPage() does not exists.

Please help! I have to use 1.8.8

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no fix for this without using NMS. I see that you've read the documentation on the spigot website, but that only applies to newer versions. However, someone has already described how to do it with NMS in this post: https://bukkit.org/threads/creating-book-guis.380796/